Unable to execute script instructions post browser launch in selenium 4.22.0 with python 3.12
below is my configuration installed
python: 3.12.2
selenium 4.22.0
Windows x64 OS
chrome driver source took from https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/126.0.6478.126/win64/chrome-win64.zip
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
serv_obj=Service("C:\VDFData\chrome-win64\chrome.exe")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=serv_obj)
driver.get("https://github.com/")
driver.close()

ran the script from command prompt:python test.py
The script was able to launch the chrome browser, but it was not executing next instruction given in the code i.e. driver.get("https://github.com/"). It was stuck or not getting executed further.
Output as below:
C:\VDFData>python test.py
C:\VDFData\test.py:24: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\V'
  serv_obj=Service("C:\VDFData\chrome-win64\chrome.exe")


browser is getting launched but later cursor gets blinked, but no further script execution happens later.
`
i.e. driver.get("https://github.com/")
`
please do let me know if any solution for this.
In chrome-win64 zip folder actually I dont see any name with chromedriver.exe rather it has chrome.exe so I have given the same in-service object.
I would like to understand is there any change from selenium 4.22.0 with python 3.12.2 to launch browser and further executing the script in selenium python. Apart from service object and locator syntax changes.

Hi is any solution for the above mentioned issue where post launch of browser via service object the driver object is being executed to next instruction.

Hi the issue got resolved after using driver option downloaded from  chromedriver (Win32) instead of Chrome (win32) from chrome driver for testing URL. Thank you.
